# Detect tscon execution from event logs

Tags: logging, remote-desktop

Is it possible to determine whether someone has hijacked a RDP session with `tscon`?

I tried to look into TerminalService-LocalSessionManager logs, the EventID 25 looks much like it, but a normal reconnect would create the same log entry.

Any ideas?